# How to increment object inside object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to increment object according to `i` value.

like this:

html

```
<div id="table">
    <a href="" id="foo1"></a>
    <a href="" id="foo2"></a>
    <a href="" id="foo3"></a>
</div>
```

js

```
$('#table a').each(function(i){
    room = {};
    room.table+i = {};
    room.table+i.chairs = $('#table a:eq('+i+')').attr('id');
});
```

But it's not working. I've googled it and didn't find an answer.
Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect `room.table+i = {};` to do? What do you mean by "increment object"? Because that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: room.table+i = {}; that is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
room['table' + i] = {};
room['table' + i].chairs = $('#table a:eq('+i+')').attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this is what im looking for! But when i try to `console.log(room)` outside the `$.each`, it returns me only the last value, ex: `table3`. How can I return all values?

Comment: just place the `room = {}` before the `$.each`, cause it's actually reset on each loop

Comment: and prefer avoiding use of global, using `var room = {}`. see here http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals